# Google sheet sending active sheet as PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that sends google sheets by email to some email, but I want to organize the email body in the code, and whenever I am making space or entering, it's not noticed by the code. Is there anything I should do so the code will understand that this is a space or go in another line?

Thank

Comment: Would you be able to provide us a sample code or preview of the code for us to further check how it was implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n` everywhere you need to start a new line.